# Getting default constructor and initializer list to work side by side

Tags: c++, c++11

I have been using initializer lists to instantiate instances of a struct, but would now like to add a default constructor.

```
struct Size {
    unsigned int width;
    unsigned int height;
};

void SizeFunc(Size const &size) { }

int main() {
    SizeFunc({1024, 768});   // OK.
}
```

Unfortunately, adding a default constructor causes an error when instantiating with the initializer list.

```
struct Size {
    Size() : width(1920), height(1080) { }

    unsigned int width;
    unsigned int height;
};

void SizeFunc(Size const &size) { }

int main() {
    Size size; // OK.
    SizeFunc({1024, 768});    // error: no matching function for call to
                              // 'Size::Size(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
}
```

What constructor do I need to add for this to work? I've tried using constructors with std::initializer_list, but have had no success so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a non-explicit constructor taking two unsigned ints that initializes the members with the arguments.

```
Size(unsigned int width, unsigned int height) : width(width), height(height) {}
```

Comment: You can also make this the default constructor by providing default arguments `(unsigned width = 1920, unsigned height = 1080)`.

Comment: @Xeo: careful with that: this constructor can also be used with one argument (using the default for the second), and thus is a converting constructor. Probably not intended and dangerous. And making it `explicit` is a bad idea, because then the implicit conversion from a braced initializer is suppressed.

Comment: @SebastianRedl can you PLEASE elaborate on why `explicit` will be a bad idea??

Comment: @Saksham Because `SizeFunc({1024, 768})` will no longer compile; you would have to write `SizeFunc(Size{1024, 768})`. Some people might see that as an advantage; I don't.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Ohh I knew this. Wonder why I asked this. Maybe because I was super sleepy at that time